# In practice, is it more efficient to instantiate inside the constructor at all times? Or instantiate inside methods that need it?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, instantiation

For example, let's say I have

```
Random random = new Random();
```

inside a constructor. It seems it would fit better inside the method that is dependent upon it (maybe a random number generator method).

But let's say that the same method has to clear an array list every time to output random numbers on each call. Would it be better to insert a `.clear()` call at the beginning inside the method? Or remove the instantiation of the array list from the constructor and insert it into this method?

Comment: Remember, [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).  Scope things as tightly as you can.

Comment: Efficiency isn't the right metric to measure here. Think about readability, locality, keeping related code together, separation of concerns, etc.

Comment: `clear()` - O(n).
.The garbage collector removes it with O(1). So if you don't need to keep your collection, don't keep it and instatiate a new one

Comment: btw the garbage collector will remove every 'cleared' object, so you should better rely on the java when you're trying to manage such memory usage

Comment: @azurefrog I like your reply, sometimes picturing the program as a whole confuses me. Very helpful!

Comment: @RostyslavBarmakov this was a specific practice question from the past, for a lotterynumber generator and every subsequent call needed to be cleared to pass a test. Does the garbage collector still clear the arraylist?

Comment: @wild_o I mean if you call `clear()`, actually it just executes for-loop and assigns `null` to each entry. But the values are still in a heap, and `GC` still should clean-up them. So it will do the same when you just reassign a new value to your list. `clear()` is redundant in this case. Also, it makes some additional logic and 
worsen readability.